# How to interrupt the "Data Store Garbage Collection" or make it faster?

Tags: jackrabbit

with "Data Store Garbage Collection" I mean the [Apache Jackrabbit one](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/archive/wiki/JCR/DataStore_115513387.html#DataStore-DataStoreGarbageCollection)

I'm working on an application having a huge database repository, **its default_bundle Oracle table is 55G big**

In that application, the data store garbage collector has been disabled for years, so if you know Jackrabbit you know we have a lot of gigabytes of trash in the global datastore in file-system.
So the Datastore Garbage Collection should be the only solution, but I'm worried that it will run for days, maybe weeks scanning the whole repository, so I would like to be able to interrupt it but I have no idea how to do it or I would like to run it in an alternative faster way, step by step for example, that is scanning partially repository for example.

Thanks

Comment: Jackrabbit classic or Jackrabbit Oak?

Comment: Hi, the classic one, 2.14.0 exactly, thanks

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to update to 2.14.8, but of course that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: In other applications using a more recent version of the product we use 2.18.0, while in the test environment of this specific app for which I'm asking we'are using 2.16.1.
But I believe there is not so much difference, am I wrong?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Ok @JulianReschke so how would you suggest approaching the problem? In Jackrabbit users ml I have received no answer :( so I believe there is no simple solution to my question, thanks

Comment: I would guess that you would need to stop the Java thread that is running the GC...

Comment: Ok but what exactly will I stop? There are two steps, mark and sweep so I need to know what's happen if I stop while marking and what while sweeping, I'go deeper in source code but you that contribute to Jackrabbit what do you think?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that piece of code.